# Auto merge using regex

Tags: git, kdiff3, mergetool

KDiff3 has option **automatic merge regular expression**. In case of conflict KDiff3 resolve it automaticlly using REMOTE changes. But I want to resolve it using LOCAL changes.

My question: Is there possibility to resolve conflict automatically by some regex using LOCAL changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution.

Remote changes were applied because GitExtensions set Local as B (second file) and Remote as C (third file). But in documentation of KDiff3 you can read

```
KDiff3 offers automatic merge for these items. For simple lines that match the "Auto merge regular expression"-option in all input-files KDiff3 will choose the line from B or - if available - from C
```

I ran KDiff3 in command line and set file with local changes as **third** argument, file with remote changes as **second** argument.

```
kdiff3.exe  BASE_FILE  REMOTE_FILE  LOCAL_FILE  -m  -o  OUTPUT_FILE
```

Now, conflicts are resolved using LOCAL changes